# Setting listener to custom view

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I have a `view` which dynamically add a `custom view` made with a `checkbox`, an `edittext`and a `imagebutton`. I want to add listeners to the `imagebutton`to delete the `custom view`(or set the visibility to `gone` if the `imagebutton`is pressed. This is my code so far, starting with the more basic stuff:

```
 public void addView() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_task_list, null);
        ImageButton img_btn = findViewById(R.id.delete);
        EditText name_et = findViewById(R.id.todo);
        CheckBox done_cb = findViewById(R.id.done);
        img_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Do something
            }
        });
        parentLayout.addView(view, parentLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
```

This works as long as I don't have the listener. With it, I get this error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`

It works if I set the listener like this:
`img_btn.setOnClickListener(this);` and then use the `OnClick`method from the activity. There I have:

```
case R.id.delete:
        v.getParent().
        break;
```

But then I can't set the visibility to `gone` nor remove it.

This is my first time adding `custom views`, so I'm not sure what I'm missing, if I should make a class, set the listener from other way, or how to access it.

Comment: Scrobot's answer should solve your problem but you should consider using [ListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView) or even better : [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) to add things dynamically. You can easily setup listeners for click, checkbox etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to call `findViewById` from inflated view. It should help.

```
public void addView() {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_task_list, null);
        ImageButton img_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        EditText name_et = view.findViewById(R.id.todo);
        CheckBox done_cb = view.findViewById(R.id.done);
        img_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Do something
            }
        });
        parentLayout.addView(view, parentLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
```